# threading.Timer - Not executing every 30 seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

For my application, I have a function that checks every 30 seconds the mouse position. If the mouse is at the same position after 300 seconds, the program is stuck and it needs a restart. Because I had some troubles with this function I decided to add 
`print(pos_x_one, pos_x_two)` and I discovered after the program is running for some time this line isn't printed every 30 seconds but almost every 5 seconds! I don't care about a small error, but 25 seconds off is way too much. Any ideas what the issue can be?

```
def printit():
    threading.Timer(30, printit).start()
    global stuck_counter
    global check_stuck

    pos = pyautogui.position()
    stuck_counter += 1

    if stuck_counter %2 == 0:
      pos_x_one = pos.x
    else:
      pos_x_two = pos.x

    print(pos_x_one, pos_x_two) 

    if pos_x_one == pos_x_two:
      check_stuck += 1
      if check_stuck == 10:
        print("STUCK!")
        check_stuck = 0
        restarting()
    else:
      check_stuck = 0
```

Comment: Code indention needs to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer I was calling the printit function every loop of the program, still can't believe it >.<.